# Xamarin Android error: <identifier> expected package @string

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

In my app I tried reducing the amount of places I needed to update a string name, so I added a string in the Resources/values/Strings.xml file, but when I tried to test my build I got a weird error that I coudnt find a solution on, and have no idea why its doing that.

Someone know anything about this?

heres the xml code:

`<resources>
  <string name="service_name">ITMNotificationService</string>
</resources>`

Using it in a Service attribute:

```
[Service (Label = "@string/service_name"
    , Name = "@string/service_name"
    , Icon = "@drawable/ITMIcon"
    )]
```

**And the error in the console;**

[image]

Comment: why is this tagged under `c#`

Comment: The **Service** attribute is in a C# script, using Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` parameter for the `ServiceAttribute` is defining the Java class name that will be used in the ACW that is generated at *compile time*.

Thus the **literal string** of `@string/service_name` can not be used for a Java class name as that is invalid. Typically this would be the fully-qualified class name that includes your package id, ie.

```
Name = "com.sushihangover.coolapp.mywickedservice"
```

You could define this via a C# `const` string, but not an Android resource-based string value.

Note: You do not need to define the `Name` and Xamarin will auto-generated one via an MD5 hash routine. You then use `typeof` instead of the Java class name when calling the `StartService` method.

Comment: So I cant use the @string in the attribute? Thats slightly disappointing. As for using typeof for starting the service, Im already using it in that way. The reason im giving it a name is for other parts of the app that require a target, and is better to use string instead of **typeof**

Comment: @Nevaran Just as you could not use a Resource-based string in Android  Studio to name a Java class, you can not do it here either... it must be a constant string value in order to be available as compile time.

Comment: Understood.
To be frank, im not much familiar with java so I dont really know any java classes and how they work. Maybe its time to also learn some java? haha